# Connection has already been closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling, tomcat8

Tomcat 8

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
    destroy-method="close">      
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />        
    <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="200" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="50" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="50000" />
    <property name="fairQueue" value="true" />
    <property name="logAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />    
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${database.validationQuery}" />
</bean>
```

**App is running on tomcat 8 and starts giving the error after 15 20 mins**

SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Connection has already been closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1542)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:738)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:794)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:209)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:303)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:310)

Comment: ..and what should we examine? where is the code? any details on when this happens? provide [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Comment: removed this <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" /> after cahnge app is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed this `<property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />` after change app is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Increase the value of removeAbandonedTimeOut in tomcat-resources.xml so that it is set to the longest running query the application may have.